# PySpark bug when formatting date in a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I discovered a curious bug in PySpark "to_date" function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, col
from datetime import date

df = spark.createDataFrame([(date(2020,12,26),)], ['t'])
df1 = df.select(to_date(df.t, 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('dt')).withColumn('fn1',cfg.date_format(col('dt'),'YYYYMMdd'))
df1.show()
```

This gets the output below:

[image]

But if you use the same code for a date that's one day later,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, col
from datetime import date

df = spark.createDataFrame([(date(2020,12,27),)], ['t'])
df1 = df.select(to_date(df.t, 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('dt')).withColumn('fn1',cfg.date_format(col('dt'),'YYYYMMdd'))
df1.show()
```

You'll get:

[image]

The same goes for dates after 2020-12-27, but never for dates before 2020-12-25.

Comment: `yyyy` is not the same as `YYYY` - it looks like you're using the wrong format

Answer (score 1):

`Y` means week year (year based on ISO week) while `y` means a normal year. `2020-12-27` belongs to ISO week 1 of year 2021, so you will get 2021 if you use `Y`. I think you meant to use `y` in your `date_format` function.

Note that week-based datetime patterns (such as `y` and `w`) are deprecated in Spark 3.